# Liferay Blade - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jpm4j is not installed. Missing registry key HKLM/Software/JPM4j/Home

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-blade-cli

i was trying to install Liferay Blade CLI using command Line,

```
'java -jar biz.aQute.jpm.run-latest.jar -g init'
```

but i am getting an error as follows.

```
'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jpm4j is not installed. Missing 
registry key HKLM/Software/JPM4j/Home
    at aQute.jpm.platform.Windows.readkey(Windows.java:56)
    at aQute.jpm.platform.Windows.<clinit>(Windows.java:24)
    at aQute.jpm.platform.Platform.getPlatform(Platform.java:36)
    at aQute.jpm.lib.JustAnotherPackageManager.<init>(JustAnotherPackageMana
ger.java:114)
    at aQute.jpm.main.Main.run(Main.java:750)
    at aQute.jpm.main.Main.main(Main.java:83)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at aQute.jpm.platform.Platform.getPlatform(Platform.java:36)
    at aQute.jpm.lib.JustAnotherPackageManager.<init>(JustAnotherPackageMana
ger.java:114)
    at aQute.jpm.main.Main.run(Main.java:750)
    at aQute.jpm.main.Main.main(Main.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
jpm4j
 is not installed. Missing registry key HKLM/Software/JPM4j/Home
    at aQute.jpm.platform.Windows.<clinit>(Windows.java:37)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jpm4j is not installed. 
Missing registry key HKLM/Software/JPM4j/Home
    at aQute.jpm.platform.Windows.readkey(Windows.java:56)
    at aQute.jpm.platform.Windows.<clinit>(Windows.java:24)
    ... 4 more'
```

Is there anything to be added/changed in the system files?
please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Why not install this way? https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/installing-blade-cli

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved in this way.

downloaded **JPM** from  https://github.com/jpm4j/jpm4j.installers/blob/master/dist/biz.aQute.jpm.run.jar?raw=true﻿

Go to the downloaded location and run 
`"java -jar biz.aQute.jpm.run.jar -g init"` 
in command prompt

Go bin directory of JPM in C, open command prompt and run,

```
"jpm platform path -a"
```

open environmant variables, **path->edit** add `;C:\JPM4J\bin`

To test,

```
test->jpm
```

open the bin folder in command prompt, run

```
 "jpm install -f https://releases.liferay.com/tools/blade-cli/latest/blade.jar"
```

To test test->blade